# Which is more efficient: atomically modifying an array or synchronizing access to it?

Tags: java, performance, synchronization, atomic

Consider these two code samples:

```
private final Player[] players = new Player[MAX_PLAYERS + 1];
private int playerCount;

public boolean addPlayer(Player player) {
    synchronized (players) {
        for (int i = 1; i < players.length; i++) {
            if (players[i] == null) {
                players[i] = player;
                playerCount++;
                player.setIndex(i);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public void removePlayer(Player player) {
    synchronized (players) {
        players[player.getIndex()] = null;
        playerCount--;
    }
}

public Player[] getPlayers() {
    synchronized (players) {
        return players;
    }
}

public int getPlayerCount() {
    synchronized (players) {
        return playerCount;
    }
}
```

and...

```
private final AtomicReferenceArray<Player> players = new AtomicReferenceArray<Player>(MAX_PLAYERS + 1);
private final AtomicInteger playerCount = new AtomicInteger();

public boolean addPlayer(Player player) {
    for (int i = 1; i < players.length(); i++) {
        if (players.get(i) == null) {
            players.set(i, player);
            playerCount.incrementAndGet();
            player.setIndex(i);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public void removePlayer(Player player) {
    players.set(player.getIndex(), null);
    playerCount.decrementAndGet();
}

public AtomicReferenceArray<Player> getPlayers() {
    return players;
}

public AtomicInteger getPlayerCount() {
    return playerCount;
}
```

Now, I know that accessing an array normally is very efficient. However, I know that synchronization can be costly. On the other side, atomic operations do not need to be synchronized, but I would guess that `players.get(i)` is not as efficient as `players[i]`. So, which of these samples would give me best performance if I were to use it in a game setting? I have the server designed so that each new player has a thread dedicated to them. And every time they finish connecting and logging in, they add themselves to the list of players, via `addPlayer(Player)`. When a player disconnects, they remove themselves from the list of players, via `removePlayer(Player)`. Since these operations are invoked from different threads, synchronization is definitely needed. 
So which should I use?

Comment: What about the bug setting element to null instead of player?

Comment: @Bohemian Thanks. I just wrote this up by hand.

Comment: If you're writing a client-server game, the time used for synchronization will be infinitesimal compared to the time used for communication. Write bug-free code first, in the simplest possible way, then focus on micro-optimizations when they add value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of these questions on SO can be answered with "have you measured it" and can be very dependent upon your environment. However, whatever solution you choose:

> And every time they finish connecting and logging in, they add
>   themselves to the list of players, via addPlayer(Player)

the cost of connecting/logging in etc. across a network will *massively* dwarf any efficiency you're concerned about.

This assertion:

> However, I know that synchronization can be costly

used to be more of a concern. Synchronisation nowadays is substantially less costly.

For the above, I really wouldn't worry about it. Get your solution working, and then determine if the above is sufficiently inefficient to warrant reworking. I see little in the above performance-related to cause me concern.

Comment: Yeah I think everyone is right. This concern over a little thing is a bit silly. Thanks everyone for your input.

Answer (score 1):

only option 1 is thread safe.

Option 2 checks if `player[i]` is null in a non thread safe way.

Comment: It's not that the check is unsafe, it's that the following `.set` may be overwriting a non-null player. The thread which checks if it's null could be put on hold and another thread add a value at index `i` before the first thread calls `set`.

Comment: If you change line 7 of the second example to:

    players.compareAndSet(i, null, player);

That should hopefully correct that issue.

Comment: The check for null is not made within a synchronized block, so it may mot *still* be null on the next line. Colselaw's compareAndSet idea should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest way to write it

```
private final List<Player> players = new CopyOnWriteArrayList(); // thread safe

public boolean addPlayer(Player player) {
    return players.add(player);
}

public void removePlayer(Player player) {
    players.remove(player);
}

public List<Player> getPlayers() {
    return players;
}

public int getPlayerCount() {
    return players.size();
}
```

Note: this won't work

```
public Player[] getPlayers() {
    synchronized (players) {
        return players;
    }
}
```

as you won't be able to use the array returned in a safe way.  Given you are only accessing a final field, synchronized won't do anything.

Comment: That would work. But I forgot to mention in the description that the ordering of the players does matter.

Comment: @MartinTuskevicius In that case you can use a `List`